# Preventing xss attack in java web app while saving actual values in database

Tags: java, security, xss

In a Recent scan of our java based web application through AppScan it was found that the application was prone to XSS attacks.
I did my research and found that a ServletFilter was probably the easiest way to protect the application.
I introduced the filter where I extended HttpServletRequestWrapper (because java does not allow request param to be changed, there is no request.setParam method). I introduced a sanitize method there and here is what it does

```
result = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize( input);

// Avoid null characters
result = result.replaceAll("\0", "");

// Clean out HTML
result = Jsoup.clean( result, Whitelist.none() );
```

Post this change, it was good, I tested for XSS vulnerabilites myself and most of them were fixed. But this posed another problem. Suppose I have a form to create a product, and in product name a user enters something like

```
<script>alert('somethingStupid')</script>
```

Now Ideally I should be able to save this to database, but still be protected from XSS attack. Not sure what to do in my filter or anywhere else to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML-injection is an output-stage issue, caused by forgetting to encode text when injecting it into a context where characters are special. ESAPI offers encoders for various contexts, as discussed by @Zakaria. If you use these consistently, each in the correct context, you have fixed injection-related XSS issues.

If you are using purely JSTL tags like `<c:out>` for your templating, these will also HTML-escape by default. In general, it is best to generate HTML using a templating system that works HTML-escaping out for you automatically, because otherwise you are likely to forget to manually encodeForHTML occasionally.

(Aside: on project where I am compelled to use the mostly-terrible owasp-esapi-java library, my preference is for `encodeForXML` over the HTML encoders, as it produces output that is safe for HTML content and quoted attribute values whilst not needlessly attempting to produce entity references for non-ASCII characters. I would typically try to avoid injecting into JavaScript string literals; it is typically easier and more maintainable to inject run-time content into HTML `data-` attributes and read them from separate JavaScript DOM code.)

Trying to filter out HTML at the input stage is a lamentably still-popular but completely misguided approach. It prevents you from entering HTML-like input when you need to—as you have found out, with the `<script>` example. Indeed, if StackOverflow used such an input filter we would not be able to have this conversation.

What's more, it's not resilient: there are many ways to smuggle potential injections past input filters. To make a filter effective you'd have to consider blocking pretty much all punctuation, which is generally not considered acceptable. Plus, any data that gets into your application by means other than request parameters won't be vetted.

Input validation is great for enforcing business rules on the formats of particular input fields, and can be used to filter out input that you never want, like control characters. But it's the wrong place to be worrying about escaping or removing HTML. The time to do that is when you're creating HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Cross Site Scripting (XSS) is a security issue which occurs when there is no mechanism of validating user input so the result will be an exploitable javascript code generally.

3 types of XSS are known : Reflexive XSS, DOM-based XSS and Persistant XSS.

In your case and since you're using OWASP ESAPI, canonicalizing inputs is not enough, sure it's a good way to defense against Untrusted URL in a SRC or HREF attribute but it's not enough.

You should Follow thess Rules : Source ( [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet of OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) ) (here are some rules for further reading follow the link) :

1- HTML Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Element Content: see the example :

```
 String safe = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML( request.getParameter( "input" ) );
```

2- Attribute Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into HTML Common Attributes :

```
String safe = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute( request.getParameter( "input" ) );
```

3- JavaScript Escape Before Inserting Untrusted Data into JavaScript Data Values:

```
 String safe = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript( request.getParameter( "input" ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

**Choose output sanitization over input sanitization to prevent XSS Attacks.**

#### Challenges with Input Sanitization:

Encoders can be overly aggressive and modify the original input extensively. For instance, if your email ID contains `@` it might be transformed into `&#64;`—altering the intended meaning and potentially disrupting functionality.

#### Importance of Input Validation:

Ensuring data integrity through input validation is crucial. For instance, validating whether an input is a valid email before storing it in a database can inherently prevent attackers from injecting script data into your database *(the first part of an XSS attack)*. However, certain input fields, like comment boxes or HTML editors, are inherently open and can't be effectively validated.

#### Significance of Output Sanitization:

While having HTML scripts in your database may not be the primary cause of XSS attacks, executing them during HTML rendering can lead to issues. In the context of XSS prevention, it's advisable to consistently encode your output using tools like `ESAPI.encodeForHTML()`. Input validation is optional but beneficial for various reasons.

#### XSS and Single Page Applications (Angular/React):

For Single Page Applications built with technologies like Angular or React, you may not necessarily need to encode your output from the backend. These frameworks are designed to render any scripts as plain text, mitigating the risk of script execution.